# CSS width issue on resizing a list element with height 100%

Tags: html, css, height, width

I have a list of images in a slideshow with a height of 100%. The ratio of the images and of the surrounding list elements is fine when the page is rendered the first time. But when I change the size of the browser window, the images resize perfectly, but the list element keeps its width in Firefox and Chrome. So it is not changing its width to the contents width. In Safari it is working fine. Do you have any tipps to fix that?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yvwtV/

CSS

```
    html, 
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }

    ul { 
      margin: 0; 
      padding: 0; 
      list-style: none; 
    }

    .fs-wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      .fs-viewport {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        ul {
          width: auto;
          height: 100%;
          width: 9999px;
          li {
            height: 100%;
            float: left;
            display: inline-block;
            img {
              width: auto;
              height: 100%;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="fs-wrapper">    
  <div class="fs-viewport">
    <ul id="sliderName" class="slider">
      <li class="slide"><img width="150" height="100" src="image01.jpg"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img width="66" height="100" src="image02.jpg"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img width="150" height="100" src="image03.jpg"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img width="150" height="100" src="image04.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please mockup a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I created a JSFiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/yvwtV/) Best way to see the problem is to reduce the height of the browser to see more than one test image and the reload the fiddle. After that you see the problem when you are resizing the browser again.

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve? you want a fullscreen slideshow?

Comment: I want to have a fullscreen slideshow which is based on the height. So the images are always scaled to full height, but keeping the ratio in width. If the image width is not filling out the whole screen, there is already a part of the next image.

Comment: you cant have fullwidth and height with ratio if you are not going to crop it.. so use one of this plugins http://lodep.com/jquery-screen-full-width-slider/

Comment: Sorry, maybe I described it to bad. It is ok, when the next image is cropped and already partly visible with the current image of the slideshow. Also, on a smartphone in portrait mode, the image can be cropped as well on the left and the right side. I am aiming for a slideshow with a height of 100% and all the images one after the other from left to right, doesn't matter if they are cropped left or right.